# Oracle report with aggregate function, subquery and group by

Tags: oracle, report

We are writing queries to get information that clients wish to display.
There are 30 tables Oracle 10 g and using Oracle report.
We only  knew to use Union for condition in query.
Our challenges is aggregate function, subquery and group by, too. 
How can we solve the challenges?

```
>>>>>>>>>>>> CREDITS BREAK DOWN <<<<<<<<<<<<<
SELECT statement
UNION
SELECT   statement
```

According to requirement, above query is OK.
Is it possible to rewrite better way?

Comment: Who in their right mind would upvote this question.  It is not a good question...

Answer (score 3):

What kind of question is this?

How do you want us to answer such a question?

How about learning what aggregates are, learning what a group by does and finding out how to correctly group by a column.  You need to specify and provide sample data to us, with expected results.

Here is a direct link to display some aggregates with example: http://psoug.org/reference/group_by.html

Only then can we help assist in writing a query / report for you.  Did you really always use UNION in your queries and you didn't know what joins or subqueries are?  You really need a SQL Developer or a dba.

Comment: Thanks for all,

We would like to display user by class for 2000:
We tried like following but we have 2 column with User and Class.

SELECT DISTINCT CER.USER_ID,  CER.CLASS_ID FROM EDUCATION CER
WHERE CER.USER_ID IN (SELECT MAX( CE.USER_ID) FROM EDUCATION  CE
WHERE ( TO_CHAR(CE.DT,'YYYY') = 2000)
GROUP BY   CE.USER_ID)

This is our first time and appreciate for patience and understanding.

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than adding a comment to an answer.

Comment: @user564318 - you should not be using distinct, as you are misusing SQL to try to get expected results.  Post sample data and expected results in your original question because it doesn't make sense in your comment.  Here is an example, Hi guys I have this table which stores this data.  (Provide actual data).  I would like this data to be transformed to this result set (Provide actual result set).  Then we can help you.

Comment: @user564318: I strongly recommend you read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. This will help you get the most out of the StackOverflow site. To edit your question, click the "edit" link below your question text.